# Prove that $g \cdot H ∶=gHg^{−1}$ for all $g \in G$ and $H \in S_G$ is an action of $G$ on $S_G.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $S_G$ be the set of all subgroups of $G.$
Prove that $g \cdot H ∶=gHg^{−1}$ for all $g \in G$ and $H \in S_G$ is an action of $G$ on $S_G.$

I think I have no problem showing its an action, I am having trouble showing it is a function first. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean that you have trouble showing that $gH g^{-1}$ is a subgroup?

Comment: No, lets say that I already proved that ( which I did) and then was given this question later. Does this make better sense. I think I definitely needed to clarify that thanks.

Comment: so this means $gHg^{-1} \in S_G$  for all $g \in G$ after proving a subgroup

Comment: Ok, so $gHg^{-1}$ is a subgroup. This makes the action $H \mapsto gHg^{-1}$ well-defined, no? (Also, just to be sure, I am referring to $H \mapsto gHg^{-1}$ as the function.)

Comment: I agree with you that that is well defined since we know its a subgroup, but I think its from $G \rightarrow S_G$. I know when I was talking to my professor he told me I need to show it is a function first so I am slightly confused about it as you can see. I am not even sure what function I am defining haha.

Comment: When you give an explicit definition  of a map in terms of its arguments, like in $g \cdot H ∶=gHg^{−1}$, the good- definiteness is ensured by the fact no arbitrarily chosen elements do appear in the definition (in that case, you should check that the image of an element of the domain 
is  independent of this choice). So, once we know that the conjugate of a subgroup is indeed a subgroup, it's all we need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of defining a group action of $G$ on $X$ is as a group homomorphism from $G$ to the group $\DeclareMathOperator{\Sym}{Sym}\Sym X$ of bijections on $X$.

Here $X=S_G$, the set of all subgroups of $G$.

For starters (and I think you indicated you had proved it) you need to show that, for each $g$, $gHg^{-1}$ is again a subgroup.  So far, then, we have a function from $S_G$ to $S_G$.  Call it $i_g$.

$i_g$ is in fact an element of $\Sym S_G$.  You need to show $i_g$ does define a bijection on $S_G$, for each $g\in G$.  You need to check $H\stackrel{i_g}{\mapsto} gHg^{-1}$ is injective and surjective.

Next you need to check that $\phi:G\to\Sym S_G$ by $\phi(g)(H)=i_g(H)=gHg^{-1}$ is a homomorphism.

So take $g_1,g_2\in G$, and check that $\phi(g_1g_2)=i_{g_1g_2}=i_{g_1}i_{g_2}=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)$.

So $\phi(g_1g_2)(H)=i_{g_1g_2}H=g_1g_2H(g_1g_2)^{-1}=g_1g_2Hg_2^{-1}g_1^{-1}=g_1i_{g_2}Hg_1^{-1}=g_1\phi(g_2)(H)g_1^{-1}=i_{g_1}\phi(g_2)(H)=\phi(g_1)\phi(g_2)(H)\,,\forall H\in S_G$.

Thus $\phi$ is a homomorphism.

.

Comment: My trouble is the function part. I have that I need to show that $gHg^{-1} = g'H'g^{-1}'$. I want to show that they are subsets of the eachother so I am starting with $gag^{-1} \in gHg^{-1}$ for all $a \in H.$ Need some help showing its in $g'H'g^{-1}'$.

Comment: $H\mapsto gHg^{-1}$ is bijective for each $g$.  So it defines an element of $\operatorname{Sym}S_G$.

Comment: That is, if $gHg^{-1}=gH'g^{-1}$, then $H=H'$.  Remember there is an extra level of abstraction here.  The elements of $S_G$ are subgroups.

Comment: So, to each $g\in G$ corresponds a bijection.  That's the function.

Comment: Of course you also have to check that $H\mapsto gHg^{-1}$ is surjective.  And this is easy.

Comment: I am wondering why my professor wanted me to go through the motions of what I was doing above. Any suggestions on that?

Comment: I think this is probably a pretty good exercise.  I'm not exactly sure which motions you're referring to.  The so-called "inner automorphisms" are pretty important, I think.  And that's sort of what the exercise is about.  You'll encounter them again.

Comment: You must be referring to what you were doing in your first comment.  I think there's an error there.  I don't see the need to consider two different $g$'s.  You just need to check injectivity and surjectivity for each fixed $g$.

Comment: We haven't gone over automorphisms so I am not quite sure the role. But the motions I was referring to were me showing $ghg^{-1} = g'H'g^{-1}'$.

Comment: Hmm yes I see what you are saying.